# CSS data attribute conditional value selector?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors, custom-data-attribute

Given html such as :

```
<div data-points="800">Jonh</div>
<div data-points="200">Jack</div>
<div data-points="1200">Julian</div>
```

**How to select elements were the value is superior to `1000` (x>1000) ?**

Preference : via CSS selectors. If no such thing, then I will re-ask for a JQuery / JS answer.

---

Eventually used :

```
var x = 1000;
$("div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-points') > x) {
        $(this).addClass('larger-than-x'); // Or whatever
    }
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With CSS you can select elements with their attributes:

```
div[data-points] {  }
```

or the value of their attributes:

```
div[data-points="800"] {  }
```

but you can't use conditions in CSS.
I would recommend you to use a javaScript solutions for this problem which can be so easy, for example, using jQuery you can do something like:

```
$("div[data-points]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-points') > 1000) {
        $(this).addClass('larger-than-1000'); // Or whatever
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the only way to do it but at this point you may as well manually add the class IMO

Comment: Cool. Would do a great combo with localStorage. I validate the answer as it seems to be the only way to proceed :]

Comment: They should add a selector for this, IMO.

Comment: How would such a selector even work? You'd have to assume the value is always numeric. What if the value reflected in the markup isn't numeric? Also, what if the value *in the selector* isn't numeric? Should it match nothing, or be invalid? These are all things you have to consider when proposing a selector.

Comment: @BoltClock I just proposed a simple solution to a question that wanted to check the numbers. In real life you always have to validate the attribute selection results.

Comment: My bad, I was talking to Yuval A. but didn't want to ping them over something like this.

Comment: @YuvalA. Yet another way **CSS is an abomination.** Perfectly reasonable feature and it can only be implemented by a standards committee.